# How to convert to a specific type when the originating type is unknown?

Tags: c#, .net, types

This code is a representation of my logic. Obviously it does not work. Please advise on how to make it work.

```
switch (ObjectToControl.GetType().ToString())
{
    case "DataList":
        DataList Controled = (DataList)ObjectToControl;
        break;
    case "DetailsView":
        DetailsView Controled = (DetailsView)ObjectToControl;
        break;
    case "FormView":
        FormView Controled = (FormView)ObjectToControl;
        break;
    case "ListView":
        ListView Controled = (ListView)ObjectToControl;
        break;
    default:
        GridView Controled = (GridView)ObjectToControl;
        break;
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with 'Controled' after the switch?

Comment: Elisha's comment is very pertinent. The answer to this is highly dependent on what you plan to do after the conversion takes place.

Answer (score 3):

Why convert it at all?

All these types inherit from Control.  Just type the return value of the method as Control, and cast the object to Control.

```
return ObjectToControl as Control;
```

If, somewhere else, you need to execute functionality that only one of the types listed can handle, then at *that* point, in *that* method, check to ensure that it is of the proper type before casting and calling the methods which only exist on that specific type..

```
   if (objecttoControl is TypeToCheck)
       (objecttoControl as TypeToCheck).[MethodName](parameters);
```

or..

```
   TypetoCheck myObj = objecttoControl as TypeToCheck;
   if(myObj != null) myObj.[MethodName](parameters);
```

The first approach is to be preferred when there is a strong possibility of getting objects that are not instances of `TypeToCheck` (as in the scenario this question poses).  The second approach is better when the situation is such that you expect only instances of `TypeToCheck` to get to that line of code...

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
ObjectToControl.GetType()
```

with

```
ObjectToControl.GetType().Name
```

if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Until a `CompletelyDifferent.DataList` comes along.

Answer (score 1):

GetType().ToString() returns the fully-qualified namespace. A "ListView" will be returned as "System.Windows.Forms.ListView".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    object Controled = null; // Default is that we don't know what this is
    if (ObjectToControl is DataList)
        Controled = ObjectToControl as DataList;
    else if (ObjectToControl is DetailsView)
        Controled = ObjectToControl as DetailsView;
    else if (ObjectToControl is FormView)
        Controled = ObjectToControl as FormView;
    else if (ObjectToControl is ListView)
        Controled = ObjectToControl as ListView;
    else if (ObjectToControl is GridView)
        Controled = ObjectToControl as GridView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is using the "is" keyword:

```
if(ObjectToControl is DataList)
{
  DataList Controled = (DataList)ObjectToControl;
  //Do something specific to your data list
}
else if(ObjectToControl is DetailsView)
{
  DetailsView Controled = (DetailsView)ObjectToControl;
  //Do something specific to your details view
}
//etc
```

This tends to be a code smell implying you have an issue with your design though if you don't know the type of class up front.

Comment: Fails; `Controled` falls out of scope after the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
if (ObjectToControl is CheckBox){

    ((CheckBox)ObjectToControl).IsChecked = true;
    //Code Here
}

else if (ObjectToControl is Textbox){

    //Code Here
}
```

This will avoid namespace confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If the originating type is unknown and can't be discovered then there's no valid conversion you can do. Having said that, that should never happen.

As `ObjectToControl.GetType().ToString()` returns the fully qualified name of the class, so your code will always hit the `default` case as it stands.

Can you be more specific about the nature of your problem? Is it compile time or run-time for example?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectToControl.GetType().ToString() will return the namespace + class name. Maybe that's why you don't get hits in your switch.